# In story telling using Month, Date and Year from the past

Tags: technical-writing

When you are narrating and you would like to state the month, date and year from the past like September 8, 2019. As an introduction to your sentence, is it right to say "It was September 8, 2019, when we blank blank…"?

Comment: Can you clarify what type of writing you're doing (storytelling/creative writing like in the title or technical writing like the tags)? Also why do you think there's a problem with your sentence exactly?

Answer (score 1):

There are several prepositions and phrases that can introduce a date. "It was...." is one such. Here are some suggestions:

"On July 4, 1776, the Continental Congress convened..."

"The morning of Oct. 8, 1871 was bright and hot in Chicago..."

"Five days before Christmas, on Saturday, Dec. 20, 1958, a baby was born in Elmhurst, Illinois.

"August 24, 1993 marked the end of an era for Dade County, Florida, when Hurricane Andrew damaged or destroyed nearly every structure in a 300-square-mile area.

"The events of January 6, 2022 have been documented in countless articles and videos."

"According to the Gregorian calendar, it was Jan. 1, 1984, but on the Chinese calendar, it was the year 4681."